# JavaFX: EventFilter for two (different) events at the same time

Tags: javafx, event-handling, mouseevent

is there a way to handle a `MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED` event together with a `ScrollEvent.ANY`? I want to react while **both** events are triggered. Currently while the mouse is pressed, the scrolling does not take effect.

```
public class HorizonScroll extends Application {

    public final int SCENE_WIDTH = 800;
    public final int SCENE_HEIGHT = 600;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setPrefSize(100,600);
        scrollPane.setHmax(1000);
        scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);



        scrollPane.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
            System.out.println("Pressed");
        });


        scrollPane.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, e -> {
            System.out.println("Released");
        });

        scrollPane.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, e -> {
            System.out.println("Scrolling");

        });

        

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT);
        stage.setTitle("HorizonScroll");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        root.getChildren().addAll(scrollPane);


        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
```

This is my current dummy. What I want to achieve is something like:

```
...

scrollPane.addEventFilter(Inputevent.ANY, e -> {
     if(e.getEventType() == SCROLL && e.getEventType() == MOUSE_PRESSED) {
      //scrollPane.setHvalue( + 10 or whatever)
```

So I want to implement a horizontal scroll with the mousewheel while pressing the mouse button.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: not that I know of - you have to code it yourself (f.i. by toggling some flag in pressed/released). Hmm .. what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Seems like only one event can be handled by a node at once. I want to scroll horizontal while clicking.

Comment: _I want to scroll horizontal while clicking_ don't understand what you mean - so same procedure as always: [mcve] please :)

Comment: @kleopatra I posted my code snipped. Hopefully this describes my problem better.

Comment: As suggested, just set/unset a flag in mouse pressed/released and check it in the scroll event handler. FWIW, I use a trackpad exclusively, and I think the functionality you're implementing here would be impossible to perform with a trackpad.

Comment: @James_D I tried that before but it seems that while the press-event is triggered no other event can pass through? This is just a small project which will only work with a normal mouse.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on Windows 10 with JavaFX 16. Even while the mouse is pressed any node can still receive scroll events. Though a single event having two event types is impossible (i.e. `type == MOUSE_PRESSED && type == SCROLL` will always be `false`); you'd have to use a flag as already suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers are fired on a single event at a time, and the Event can only be of a single type.  In order to do what you want, you'll need to establish some kind of **State** and then toggle it off and on via the event handlers.  Since you already have `MOUSE_PRESSED` and `MOUSE_RELEASED` captured, it's easiest to establish "is the mouse button pressed" as a state.  Then check the state inside the event handler for scrolling.

Like so:

```
public class HorizonScroll extends Application {

    public final int SCENE_WIDTH = 800;
    public final int SCENE_HEIGHT = 600;
    private BooleanProperty mousePressed = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setPrefSize(100, 600);
        scrollPane.setHmax(1000);
        scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
            mousePressed.set(true);
            System.out.println("Pressed");
        });

        scrollPane.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, e -> {
            mousePressed.set(false);
            System.out.println("Released");
        });

        scrollPane.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, e -> {
            if (mousePressed.get()) {
                System.out.println("Scrolling - pressed");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Scrolling - not pressed");
            }
        });

        stage.setTitle("HorizonScroll");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(scrollPane), SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

I will add that the only way I could get the scrolling event handler to trigger was to use the scroll wheel on my mouse.  Clicking on the scroll bar and dragging it did not fire the event.